# People search value not returning results

Tags: 2010, search, people-search, crawl, crawled-property

This is for SharePoint 2010.

Hello,

We have added a custom field to our People Search results called Foreign Languages.  If you search for a person, the value shows up in the results.  However, if you try to search by those values, say "Russian", no results are displayed.

I believe I have all the necessary options checked for it:

Metadata Properties>Edit Managed Property>**Property**>Allow this property to be used in scopes

Metadata Properties>Edit Crawled Property>**Property**>Include values for this property in the search index

We run a full crawl every Sunday.

I think that's it; I'll be more than happy to provide more information if needed.  I'm honestly not sure what else to try or check.

Thank you,

Shawn

Comment: Just wanted to say that I got the same problem, but with me it was a field named Mobile(number). It worked before Christmas, but has recently stopped working. Please keep us updated if you find new information or a solution.

Comment: Which web part are you using ? Is it the People Results web part, Core Results web part or other?

Comment: It's the People Results web part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally dived deep enough to solve my problem.

This is according to Microsoft by design with the People Result Web Part, you can use the Core Result Web Part instead.

```
"Apparently, the issue is with the People Results web part. If you remove it and add the Core Results web part instead, point it at the People scope and configure it the same way, it should work."
```

There is a workaround which is probably better:

Go to “Add mappings for the crawled properties to the ‘ContentsHidden’ managed property (Cental Administration –> Application Management –> Manage Service Applications –> Search Service Application –> Metadata Properties).

And map to those crawled properties. And then run an incremental crawl. That should work.

Comment: Cool; I will test this tonight.  I'm currently forced to do a full crawl since I cancelled the last one.

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you very much for your help!